# Find::File preprocess

Tags: perl

I'm trying to specify a directory, and recursively find every file in the sub-directories.  After `find` chdir's into a directory, I want to do some processing before `find` reads the files.  Here is a simplified snippet that demonstrates the problem.  It doesn't recurse into the subdirectories, but it looks like it should.  I can verify that the sub-dirs and files exist because if I call `find` without the preprocess key then I get the listing.  I haven't been using Perl for that long so I'm kind of stumped.

```
find({
  wanted => \&wanted,
  preprocess => \&preprocess
}, "/home/nelson/invoices/");


# function definitions

sub wanted {
  print "Calling wanted...\n";
  print "\t" . $File::Find::name . "\n";
}

sub preprocess{
  print "Calling preprocess...\n";
  print "\t" . $File::Find::dir . "\n";
}
```

And here is the output.

```
Calling wanted...
        /home/nelson/invoices
Calling preprocess...
        /home/nelson/invoices
Calling wanted...
        /home/nelson/invoices/1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `preprocess` function is expected to return a (possibly modified) list of items to examine further. In your example, you can add `@_;` at the end of `preprocess` to return the arguments unmodified. You can do something like `grep { $_ !~ /pattern/ } @_` to filter out unwanted items, and so on.

Comment: Aha!  I didn't realize that I should be returning a list from the preprocess function call.  That is exactly what I was missing, thank you.